# Give data access to Einstein Analytics Capture from several domains

Tags: google-cloud-platform, salesforce, google-developers-console, salesforce-einstein

I started working with Einstein Analytics Capture. I need to show emails from several domains in Salesforce. But in Salesforce Einstein Analytics Capture we can have only one Service Account.

Looking at the Salesforce and Google documentation, I found no objection to a single service account managing data from multiple domains.

I need to be sure if it is possible to connect several domains to the Service Account.